# Magento2 Correct Way to get Order items

Tags: magento2, orders, cart, magento-2.0.2

I am working on M2 Payment Extension our merchant need us to send items details along with order

Everything works fine but `$order->getAllItems();` or `$order->getAllVisibleItems();` returning simple and configurable parent products so

if I have 2 products in Cart

- 1 Simple Product
- 1 Associated of configurable product

so instead of getting two products I am getting three ; one simple , associated product and its parent product;

I can try to extract correct products but I am sure it must be some other

```
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
    $order = $payment->getOrder();
    /**
     * Get All Items of Products
     */
    $productItems = $order->getAllItems() // returning 3 products where I have 2 in cart 
    $productItemsTest = $order->getAllVisibleItems(); // returning 3 products where I have 2 in cart
```

Answer (score 18):

This is how the different methods to get items from an order work:

- `getItems()`: returns array of items from loaded order item collection
- `getAllItems()`: returns array of all items that are not marked as deleted
- `getAllVisibleItems()`: returns array of all items that are not marked as deleted and do not have a parent item

So to get only the configurable product and not its associated product, `getAllVisibleItems()` is the correct method:

- the single simple item does not have a parent => **visible**
- the configurable item does not have a parent => **visible**
- the associated simple item has a parent => **not visible**

Note that unfortunately, as of [magento-2.0](/questions/tagged/magento-2.0) only `getItems()` is part of the service contract in `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface`

Comment: Thanks man but getAllVisibleitems() returning  simple and config products together so its not making sense i
if following images can help 

http://imgur.com/8ADtnUQ
http://imgur.com/LnMMuOM

Comment: The image looks correct. Or is this what you want, not what you have?

Comment: It should have return the items from cart  so just two simple products one from config and another as it is ;  I did this logic  if ($productItem->getProductType() == "simple" && ($productItem->getParentItem())) {
    continue;
   } since simple product of config was not returning price

Comment: There's a huge difference between the implementation of getAllVisibleItems in Magento 1 and Magento 2. While in M1 children products (of configurable, bundled, etc) are NOT displayed, in M2 they are. Although the implementation is the same, $item->getParentItemId() will return null in M2 for children items. Whether it's a bug or not, it's behavior varies accordingly to Magento version you're using.

Answer (score 4):

Best way to get order items is using `$order->getAllVisibleItems()`

Explained by fschmengler above,

`getAllItems():` This function returns array of all items of cart with config simple product also.

You getting three products because  you have use `$order->getAllItems()` 
you have to use `$order->getAllVisibleItems()` method to get original product.

You can check more reference from file `vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php`

```
/**
     * Retrieve quote items array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllItems()
    {
        $items = [];
        foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item $item */
            if (!$item->isDeleted()) {
                $items[] = $item;
            }
        }
        return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Get array of all items what can be display directly
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item[]
     */
    public function getAllVisibleItems()
    {
        $items = [];
        foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
            //echo $item->getId()."<br>";
            if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {
                $items[] = $item;
            }
        }
        return $items;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply  but as I explain its not working as expected see following images cart Image  http://imgur.com/8ADtnUQ and debugging image http://imgur.com/LnMMuOM

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue as you've mentioned, in my `sales_order_save_before/sales_order_save_after` observers.

I think the difference of `getAllVisibleItems()` and `getAllItems()` comes when order is created. If you're calling these functions before order creation, the output of both will remain same.

I solved this issue by loading quote from order, as follow. And I think it makes total sense, I should use Quote since order is not created. Also I was not able to get the `$order->getEntityId()` in `sales_order_save_before/sales_order_save_after` observers, so I thought to go with quote.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_quoteRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());

        $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems(); // $quote->getAllItems(); //
        $itemsData = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getData()) {
                $itemsData[] = [
                    'name' => $item->getName(),
                    'sku' => $item->getSku(),
                    'item_id' => $item->getItemId(),
                    'getParentItemId' =>$item->getParentItemId(),
                    'qty' => $item->getQtyOrdered(),
                    'product_type' => $item->getProductType(),
                    'weight' => $item->getWeight(),
                    'price' => $item->getPrice()
                ];
            }
        }
        file_put_contents('var/log/orderPlaceAfter.txt', '\n--------------------------\ItemsAllData: \n'.print_r($itemsData, TRUE), FILE_APPEND); die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Item loop and exclude the child item by the following code:

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
$order = $payment->getOrder();

foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $_item) {
     if(!$_item->getData('has_children')) { 
        continue; 
     } else {
        array_push($productIds, $_item->getProductId());
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding the following condition to check if the item has a parent .

```
If(!$_item->getParentItem())
```

Followings is the complete example code which you can use.

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
    If(!$_item->getParentItem()) {
        //Your logic here
    }
}
```